# Вопрос по сервисам в ASP.NET Core и EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework, шаблоны-проектирования

Я много уже прочитал насчет этого, после прочтения статьи на хабре решил здесь задать вопрос. Я делал в своем проекте так: создавал папочку с сервисами, где для каждой модели создавал интерфейс и класс, его реализующий. Там были все CRUD операции, ну и некоторые специфические. Но был минус, для каждой модели практически были однообразные CRUD операции, можно сказать повторение кода. Решил посмотреть про паттерн Repository. Но блин, это то же самое практически, что я делал в сервисах. Кто нибудь может пожалуйста объяснить в чем их различие, и что реализовывать там, а что там. И нужно ли это вообще?

Comment: Вы бы код свой показали, что бы можно было понять о чем вопрос или то, и в чем различия....  А по паттерну Репозиторий,  есть различные мнения,  кто то считает что это вообще не паттерна а анти- паттерн,  то есть лишний  код,    кто  то считает что его можно использовать....Как  по   мне   все  зависит  от  того   как и где применяется паттерн Репозиторий.

Comment: Вот в этом [репозитории](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Web_API/tree/master/MagicVilla_VillaAPI/Repository/IRepostiory) задан сначала универсальный интерфейс репозитория,  в проекте с API,  с сигнатурами методов для реализации CRUD операций, и обобщенными параметрами,  затем создаются интерфейсы наследники,  для сущностей из предметной области этого API (клиенты и номера в гостинице),  а затем на основании этих интерфейсов реализуются классы.  Все это позволяет, во первых абстрагироваться от БД,  а во вторых не писать кучу кода.   Так что сравните с вашим кодом,  и ответ будет очевиден.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед применением паттерна Репозиторий, обычно, не стоит задача, по уменьшению количества строк кода и их дублирования, это лишь подход к абстрактному доступу к данным и малое стремление к чистой архитектуре.

Используя этот паттерн вы очень гибко можете изменять реализацию тех или иных компонентов программы. Думаю, когда познакомитесь с тестированием, с моком данных вы это лучше увидите.

Одним из решений по минимизации дублировании кода я бы порекомендовал использовать базовые абстрактные классы, в которых будут реализованы стандартные CRUD операции и, если необходимо, что-то дополнительное.

Для `примера` можете взглянуть на этот [простенький проект](https://github.com/qFamouse/iTechArt-Pizza-Delivery/tree/master/iTechArtPizzaDelivery.Infrastructure/Data/Repositories)

Comment: Ссылку почините

Comment: @OwDafuq спасибо

Comment: @Famouse а чем репозитории отличаются от сервисов?

Comment: @Андрей В сервисах принято реализовывать бизнес-логику, логика связанная с работой приложения, например, для приложения пиццерии, заказ пиццы. А репозитории, как я написал выше, `подход к абстрактному доступу к данным`, то есть точка доступа к данным.